# NZEC(Non Zero Exit Code) error on running a Python3 program on hackerearth

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    values = list(input().split(' '))
    for val in values:
        for j in range(int(val)):
            if ((j + 1)%15) == 0:
                print("FizzBuzz")
            elif ((j + 1)%5) == 0:
                print("Buzz")
            elif ((j+1)%3) == 0:
                print("Fizz")
            else:
                print(j+1)
```

It's a simple program where the first line consists of number of test cases n(1

Followed by the next line containing the values(each value can be any integer)

You just need to print Fizz for multiples of 3, Buzz for 5, FizzBuzz for multiples of 15.

I am getting a NZEC error on hackerearth .Can't seem to figure out why.
n can be any integer here.

Comment: What's an "NZEC error on hackerearth"?

Comment: Please provide some valid context to your problem. "NZEC" error without even describing what your program does is not helpful at all.

Comment: please post you full error log,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

In Python, generally multiple inputs are separated by commas and we read them using `input() or int(input())`, but most of the online coding platforms while testing gives input separated by space and in those cases int(input()) is not able to read the input properly and shows error like NZEC (non zero exit code) as the name suggests occurs when your code is failed to return 0. To overcome this error use `raw_input().split(" ")`

No need for all those parentheses and print statements.

Try This :

```
n, k = raw_input().split(" ")
n = int(n)
k = int(k)
for num in xrange(n, k):
    if num % 15 == 0:
        msg = "FizzBuzz"
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        msg = "Fizz"
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        msg = "Buzz"
    else:
        msg = str(num)
    print msg
```